# Image fade in at scrolling of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do one simple thing. When I scroll the page an image fixed at the top should appear and disappear when scrolling at the top. I have set visibility hidden in the img selector in this way when the page load it will be hidden. unfortunately the following code doesn't work

here it is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vhe3rhLd/ and the jquery function:

**UPDATED**

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('img').fadeTo(1000, 1, function() {
      $(this).css({visibility: 'visible'});
    });
  } else {
    $('img').fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
      $(this).css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    });
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function `fadeTo()` wrong.

The parameters of `fadeTo()` are:

```
fadeTo(duration,opacity,callback)
```

So a correct way of using that is as follows:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('img').fadeTo(500, 1, function() {
      $(this).css({visibility: 'visible'});
    });
  } else {
    $('img').fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
      $(this).css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    });
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Also, the use of opacity (fadeTo) and visibility in the callback could bring you unexpected behaviour because you set de visibility after the fadeIn or fadeOut completly execute. Maybe you could avoid using the visibility and only play with the opacity like this:

```
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('img').fadeTo(500, 1);
      } else {
        $('img').fadeTo(500, 0);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
      });
$('img').hide();//Hide the image at start
```

I make  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6trg6uu/1/) to show it. Check if it fits your needs.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work well even using your way. it doesn't hide when I go to the top

Comment: I don't have that problem. I make a few tests and shows and hides without problem. I make an update of the jsFiddle to reduce duration to 100ms instead 500ms to check it better. Could you please tell me when doesn't work? Maybe i understand you wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/e6trg6uu/2/

Answer (score 0):

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhe3rhLd/6/)

the js

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
         $('img').fadeIn(600);
      } else {
         $('img').fadeOut(600);
      }
   event.preventDefault();
  });
```

and the css

```
body {
height: 2800px;
}

img {
position: fixed;
width: 300px;
display:none;

}
```

Comment: no I can't use display none because I have some content at the right of the img. It cause the shrinked of the content

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vhe3rhLd/7/

HTML:

```
<img class='hidecontent'  src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg' />
```

CSS

```
body {
height: 2800px;
}

img {
 position: fixed;
width: 300px;


}
.hidecontent{
opacity:0;
z-index:-999;
transition:all 0.5s ease;   
}

.showcontent{
opacity:1;
z-index:999;
transition:all 0.5s ease;   
}
```

JS

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
  $('img').removeClass('hidecontent').addClass('showcontent');
 } else {
  $('img').addClass('hidecontent').removeClass('showcontent');
}
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your image visible before fading it out.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('img').css({visibility: 'visible'});
        $('img').fadeTo(500, 0, function() {

    });
    } else {
         $('img').fadeTo(0, 500, function() {
         $(this).css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    });
 }
 event.preventDefault();
});
```